# How can I extend the length of my furnace run time after burner shutdown?

Tags: furnace, blower

My new furnace has a control board with preset blower run times after thermostat satisfies.  Max setting is 180 seconds.  This is not enough to purge the latent heat in the heat exchanger.  I need another minute of run time. How do I get extra time?

Comment: Make/model # of furnace?

Comment: What makes you think there's significant heat to be recovered?

Answer (score 2):

I too am like you, an old time boiler guy; 40+ years + 11 retired. My comment to you is, if your furnace fan is running on the correct fan speed and the furnace is not too oversized, the heat exchanger should be able to give up (cool down) enough so that there will be a very little waste of energy. The small amount of energy you are trying to remove may be offset by the energy the fan motor will consume. Yes, I still like the old ways that we were used to but that was then and this is now. Get used to it, the new generation has made us obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add an off delay relay, I installed one in our hose room when we cut high pressure hydraulic lines with a hot saw or steel cutoff saw a large amount of smoke is generated I added an off delay relay that turns on when the saw is started and runs after the saw stops to the setting set for. I am not sure if the cost of these relays would ever pay for themselves. I use MS4SM-AP-ADC from automation direct, Omron and Allen Bradley also have the exact functionality and wiring but cost more these are 52$ plus you would need the socket. But it could be done.